# Convert LINQ orderby to inplace list sort

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

Currently, i'm sorting a list using LINQ to objects, then doing a `ToList()` on the results:

```
var SortedPossibleMoveLocations = (from PML in PossibleMoveLocations
                                   orderby Randomiser.Next()
                                   orderby IsSameType(PML) ? (_Owner[PML] as TileFlowing).UnitsWithin : 0
                                   orderby PossibleMoveLocationOrdering(PML)
                                   select PML).ToList();
```

I want to convert this to do an inplace sort, i guess using `List<T>.Sort()` method. If i was only ordering by one thing i'd know how to do this, however, as i'm ordering by `PossibleMoveLocationOrdering` (which returns an `int`) then by `IsSameType(PML) ? (_Owner[PML] as TileFlowing).UnitsWithin : 0` which evaluates to an `int`, then by `Randomiser.Next()` (which returns a random int) i don't know how to do this.

**Question:** How do i write the comparison function (or is there a better method) to do an implace sort of the LINQ query above.

Comment: Note that multiple orderby is almost always *wrong* - that won't add the `ThenBy`, so it will actually invert the sort precedence. It should be a single orderby with multiple expressions

Comment: I understand i'll get ordering the opposite of orderby x, y, z. (Although i did write this before i knew about the single orderby syntax). That's why in the text below the code i clarify what has presidence. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To start with, specifying three `orderby` clauses is a bad idea - instead, specify multiple orderings just by using comma separation.

I'm also not keen on the idea of using `Randomiser.Next()` for ordering, but that's an aside.

Your LINQ query *should* look like this (still with `Randomiser` in for the moment):

```
var query = (from PML in PossibleMoveLocations
             orderby PossibleMoveLocationOrdering(PML),
                     IsSameType(PML) ? (_Owner[PML] as TileFlowing).UnitsWithin : 0,
                     Randomiser.Next()
             select PML).ToList();
```

Personally I'd just use dot notation for this:

```
var query = PossibleMoveLocations
                .OrderBy(pml => PossibleMoveLocationOrdering(PML))
                .ThenBy(pml => IsSameType(pml) ? 
                                    (_Owner[pml] as TileFlowing).UnitsWithin : 0)
                .ThenBy(pml => Randomiser.Next())
                .ToList();
```

To sort in place, you basically need a `Comparison<T>` or `IComparer<T>` which can test multiple things, and also an implementation which creates a comparer using properties. You can do that manually (as per Marc's code), but as it happens, I have some helper classes and extension methods in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil):

```
var comparer = ProjectionComparer<PossibleMove>
                   .Create(pml => PossibleMoveLocationOrdering(PML));
                   .ThenBy(pml => IsSameType(pml) ? ...)
                   .ThenBy(...);

list.Sort(comparer);
```

Note that using a `Randomizer` here is *definitely* a bad idea, as it will be called on each comparison (for objects with equal first parts)... this can lead to an inconsistent comparison such that `x` < `y` < `z` < `x`.

Comment: What would an alternative be to orderby by a random number in the final (all other order by values are equal) case?

Comment: Also, is using multiple orderby's a bad idea purely because of readability, or is there another reason?

Comment: @George: Basically you don't have a consistent ordering in that case. If you can't distinguish between two objects consistently, why not just return 0 when comparing them?

Comment: @George: Using multiple `orderby` clauses will be a lot less efficient - it'll reorder *everything* (relying on the stability of the ordering to preserve the "previous" orderings) rather than just checking tiebreakers. There's also the readability issue of having to specify everything backwards...

Comment: @Jon: Because i don't want the ordering to be the same as the orignal list in that case, i want a random order.

Comment: @George: As it happens, `List<T>.Sort` is unstable anyway... but to my mind if you're giving a "random" element that suggests you shouldn't be caring about the order of equivalent elements. If you really care, assign somethink like a random `long` (unlikely to be equal) to each value, and use that as the tie-breaker. Trying to sort by a comparison which is inconsistent is a really bad idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't see `ThenBy` in your `ProjectionComparer` source code. Can you point me to the correct location? I'm looking at the Feb 26, 2009 release.. there must be a more recent one.

Comment: @Millie: Will look tomorrow.

Comment: @JonSkeet Nevermind, found it. For anyone looking for it, it's in the `ComparerExt` file in the same directory, and it relies on `LinkedComparer`. Thanks for the libraries, Jon!

Answer (score 6):

Most commonly:

```
list.Sort((x,y) => {
    int result = /* first comparison, for example
                    string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name) */
    if (result == 0) result = /* second comparison,
                                 for example x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id) */
    ...
    if (result == 0) result = /* final comparison */
    return result;
});
```

or similar (perhaps in a comparer class, if it is non-trivial).